# irrklang engine was not declared at void

Tags: c++, function, void, irrklang

EDIT 2:
Solved! Use the code below and it worked!

```
irrklang::ISoundEngine* engine = irrklang::createIrrKlangDevice();
```

Just place the code above at the top of the code. (Maybe the next line of include or namespace)

---

I'm using irrKlang to play audio but I had a problem:

```
#include <irrKlang.h>

void playSound() {
    engine->play2D("src/Click.wav");
}

int main() {
    irrklang::ISoundEngine* engine = irrklang::createIrrKlangDevice();
    playSound();

    engine->drop();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it show that 'engine' (that in the void)  was not declared in this scope.

I test this at int main but it work. The problem is that it only worked at main but not at void.

Anything I can use to fix this error? Or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing you call a "void" is usually called a "function". (`void` is a type, like `int`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected. `irrklang::ISoundEngine* engine` is defined in `main` function but not in `playSound()`.

A straightforward solution would be to pass engine as an argument

```
void playSound(irrklang::ISoundEngine* engine) {
    engine->play2D("src/Click.wav");
}
```

and in `main` call it like this

```
playSound(engine);
```